# .py file opens PyCharm instead of running the script

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have written a python script (lets call it `myTest.py`) and would like to launch it from the windows command promt.

My python interpreter was added to the PATH environment variable, therefore i can launch it just fine as `python myTest.py` and it is executed successfully.

I would however like to launch it by simply typing `myTest.py` in the command promt. But if I do this, the file is opened in PyCharm and is not executed.

I have checked `assoc .py` which gives me `.py=Python.File`, as well as `ftype Python.File` which gives me `Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*`. As far as I understand this, a .py file should be launched with py.exe at the given path.
(If you are as confused as I was by the %L option of ftype, that is not mentioned in its help document: It makes no difference in my case and is equivallent to %0 and %1. Source: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2015-November/699263.html)

Can anyone explain why my script is opened in PyCharm and not launched with py.exe? What do I have to do to simply execute it instead?

**Edit:**
The answer of @Hamed169 solves the problem (thanks!), but doesnt't give any details on why there is a difference between the program that is used to open a file and the one that is returned by ftype.
For everyone that is interested in why there is a difference I have found the following question (has currently no final answer, but quite a bit of information): https://superuser.com/questions/204354/how-do-i-get-ftype-assoc-to-match-windows-explorer

Comment: what is your default program for working with python files? More specifically, if you double click on the python file, how does it behave?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right Click on a .py file

Click Properties

Click "change" in Opens with:

Select your python interpreter instead PyCharm

Run your .py files and enjoy:)

Comment: Thanks! For everyone who is interested in why there is a difference between this and ftype: Have a look at the edit of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Hame
We should change it to the python.exe file path, i.e., (in my case):
C:\Users\NEDA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32